# WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.js 10:24-31 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies

Tags: angular, timestamp, warnings, subscription

A warning message shows up when a for loop is used inside of a subscription (when I delete the for loop, the warning dissapear). I was trying to convert a Timestamp from SQL into a number readable for angular, i find a workaround but a warning appears

> import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

```
getUserTasks() {
    this.tasksSubscription = this.userService.getUserTasks(3).subscribe(tasks => {
      this.tasks = tasks;
      for (var ta of this.tasks) {
        let str = ta.startDate.split("[");
        let time = new Date(str[0]);
        ta.startDate = stringify(time.getTime());
      }
      this.TaskDataSource.data = this.tasks;
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
    );
  }
```

WARNING :

> WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/util.js 10:24-31
>
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the rest of the code, but usually that warning is prompted when you are not importing something correctly. 
I see you are using the stringify function inside of the for loop, so it could be because of that. Could you share the import line for the stringify function?

Comment: import { stringify } from '@angular/compiler/src/util';

Comment: That is the problem. You should never import from the source folder in an angular dependency. As a matter of fact, I think that function is not even exported as public API, so you shouldn't be using it at all.
Looking back at your code, you use it to parse a timestamp to string, this should do exactly the same thing:
`ta.startDate = time.getTime().toString();`
And get you rid of that warning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue importing the  stringify and removing it fixed the error.